# What irradiance does the Moon receive during a total lunar eclipse?

Tags: the-moon, astrophysics, lunar-eclipse

As we know, the total solar irradiance normally received by the Moon is about 1361 $W/m^2$ (the same as the top of the Earth's atmosphere). Of course, this changes during lunar eclipses, *but the Moon doesn't go completely dark* even during total eclipses (it's usually just a dim red). It still receives light through the Earth's atmosphere. My question is how much?

I've tried googling this, but all the search terms I could think of just gave me a bunch of unrelated astrology results. *Surely people have measured this.*

The worst case irradiance for any part of the Moon during a total eclipse is fine for my purposes, but I wouldn't mind a paper with an intensity curve over time if there are any.

Edit:
This is not a duplicate of "[Red Moon a Characteristic of all Total Lunar Eclipses?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/2166)" That question is asking if all lunar eclipses are red and/or if the amount of redness varies. I'm asking how much light hits the Moon (per second per area) during a total lunar eclipse. Furthermore, none of the answers there even mention irradiance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Red Moon a Characteristic of all Total Lunar Eclipses?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/2166/red-moon-a-characteristic-of-all-total-lunar-eclipses)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That question is about redness rather than irradiance. [Florin Andrei's answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/2192) to that question provides a link to "a list of 20th century eclipses, with a measure of the magnitude of the umbra", which is partially relevant, but it's a further step to then calculate the irradiance.

Answer (score 3):

The following is more a series of observations than a full answer, but I hope other people can fill in the details.

The [apparent magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_(astronomy)) of the full moon is -13. The apparent magnitude of the moon during a lunar eclipse will differ from eclipse to eclipse (correlated to the [Danjon scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danjon_scale) value), but let's suppose it is 0 for a certain eclipse. (Note that this magnitude is different from the (pen)umbral magnitudes mentioned on the [NASA website](https://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/LEcat5/LE2001-2100.html); these magnitudes can be computed and do not depend on the Earth's atmosphere.)

This means the full Moon is normally reflecting $100^{13/5}$ times more light than during this eclipse. I'm not sure if the [albedo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albedo) of the Moon is different for red light than it is for normal sunlight, but if not, that means the answer is $\frac{1361}{100^{13/5}} \frac{W}{m^2} \approx 8.6 \frac{\text{m}W}{m^2}$.